# Call javascript function from call?

Tags: javascript

How do i make so when i make this call

```
 client.notification("test", "test", function(){
      alert("Hello world");
 });
```

I can call the stuff inside the function(){....} in "client.notification"?

ex.

```
var client = ({"notification" : function(a,b,c){
    document.write(a + b);
    if ( .... ) {
        //call the alert stuff from the function "c"
    }
});
```

I've tried this:

```
$('#notification').click(eval(c));
```

without luck

Comment: Just like any other function. `c()`

Comment: Thanks, post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var client = ({"notification" : function(a,b,c){
    alert('inside of notification');
    c.call(); // or even `c()`
}});

client.notification("test", "test", function(){
    alert("inside of callback");
});
```